# Clearing a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

So I have a JList that I add data to when a method is called. I want to be able to refresh the data in the JList but everytime I try and remove from the JList, the new data is appended to the old. So basically when the button is pressed, it calls the method and the JList should be updated (old data cleared and new data read in).

I tried clearing the data from the model and when I request the size, it says it is 0, but it is still appended. I also tried deleting from the List itself. Driving me nuts, any help would be appreciated. This is basically how I am doing, where "new Data" is changing upon every method call.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);

public void method(){
 if(model.size() > 0){
 model.removeAllElements();
 model.clear();
 list.removeAll();
 }

model.addElement("new Data");
model.addElement("new Data");

}
```

Comment: Please provide your complete code; what you wrote here should work. There is something that you are doing and we are not seeing.

Answer (score 3):

To start with, don't call `list.removeAll`, while it's unlikely to do anything, it's not wise to mess with components this way.

The simplest solution is to just replace the `JList`'s `ListModel`...

```
list.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
```

or, in your case, something like...

```
model = new DefaultListModel();
list.setModel(model);
model.addElement("new Data");
```

If this isn't working, then you are probably shadowing your variables, in this case, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: thanks so much for the reply. When I just added the first solution, my JList cleared but when I used the second block of code you provided, the data was mixed with the old data.

Comment: There is really no need to create a new model. Calling `clear` on the existing one should be enough, but there is something off in the OP's code which is not provided.

Comment: The code I provided is nearly identical minus the adding data part, which in this case isn't necessary. Any other ideas?

Comment: @alterfox I agree, but I was working of the idea of "simplest".  Replacing the model should guarantee that there is no correlation between the old and the new models.  It also discounts the use of `DefaultListModel` as well, as not all `ListModel`s have a `clear` method.

Comment: @jjamzn Then there is something going in your code that you haven't shown us, as both your and my code should work. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: remove caused an perfomance issue if is there mode than 999 Items (bug or feature, a few times here about ...) I'm would be creating a new DefaultListModel instead of removing all Items